# screeps room memory seems to reset every tick

Tags: screeps

I'm trying to store link ID's in individual room memory, but it seems that the memory resets every tick. If I run:

```
 Game.rooms.W45N28.memory.sourceLink = id
```

in the command line, and then immediately call `Game.rooms.W45N28.memory.sourceLink`, it returns undefined. However, if I add

```
Game.rooms.W45N28.memory.sourceLink = id
```

to main and then call `Game.rooms.W45N28.memory.sourceLink` in the command line, it properly returns id. But if I then remove it from main, it goes back to returning undefined. I can't find anywhere in my scripts where it would reset the room memory.
Is there a certain way one supposed to add things to memory and I'm doing it incorrectly?

Comment: fixed formatting for improved readability

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not accidentally resetting the room's memory or setting the sourceLink field to `undefined` by accident? If you set a field in the `Memory` object to `undefined` you're effectively doing the same as `delete Memory.<path>`.

The Memory object is alive each the whole tick so I doubt this is a bug in the game, because almost everyone relies on the `memory` property of the Room object.

Comment: I'm fairly certain I'm not, and even so, I tried moving to a different branch with absolutely no code at all, only a main, which was empty, and it still resets every time i set it. i also tried putting rooms.W45N28 in the memory watch list and making a sourceLink field manually, but as soon as i would reload it, it went back to being undefined. this happens with all my rooms by the way, not only W45N28, but rooms are the only things it happens to, everything else's memory works fine

Answer (score 0):

Just like Toolmaker already wrote, it should work your way and the rooms memory should be stored. Maybe you try to store live object data as mentioned in [Working with memory > Storing game objects](http://support.screeps.com/hc/en-us/articles/203016642-Working-with-memory)?
*"The Memory object is for storing JSON data and cannot contain live objects references."*

Of course I also use the room memory and it works like a breeze. I set this memory once (see my example below) and it will be saved forever.

---

I am using a specific module 'z.settings' for all my room settings, among others. Then, whenever I need to change something fundamental, I do this in the 'z.settings' and let it update everything. Here's the concept:

```
-- MAIN

// Make this true to update all settings globaly! Should be made false again afterwards to save CPU.
if (1 == 2) {
    var globalSettings = require('z.settings');
    globalSettings.update();
};

-- MODULE 'z.settings'

var myRooms = [
    { name: 'W45N28', active: true,
                    someData: {
                        abc: 1,
                        def: 2,
                        ghi: 3,
                    },
                    creepJob: {
                        amount_Harvester: 3,
                        amount_Upgrader: 3,
                        body_Harvester: [WORK,WORK,WORK,CARRY,MOVE,MOVE,MOVE],
                        body_Upgrader: [WORK,WORK,WORK,WORK,CARRY,CARRY],
                    },
    },
    { name: 'W45N29', active: false,
                    someData: {
                        zyx: 1,
                        wvu: 2,
                        tsr: 3,
                    },
                    creepJob: {
                        amount_Harvester: 5,
                        amount_Upgrader: 2,
                        body_Harvester: [WORK,CARRY,MOVE,MOVE],
                        body_Upgrader: [WORK,WORK,CARRY],
                    },
    },
];

module.exports = {
    update() {
        // Loop through all myRooms and process all active ones.
        for (i=0; i < myRooms.length; i++) {
            if (myRooms[i].active) {
                var room = Game.rooms[myRooms[i].name];
                // Write the memory of the current room.
                room.memory.someData = myRooms[i].someData;
                room.memory.creepJob = myRooms[i].creepJob;
                console.log('Updating settings for room ' + myRooms[i].name + '...')
            };
        };
        console.log('--- All settings have been updated!')
    },
};
```

As you can see, you just have to set the `if` in the MAIN `true` like `(1 == 1)` **for one tick** to update everything and then set it back to something `false` like `(1 == 2)`. This way you have everything fundamental in one place and do not need to search for all basic memory stuff everywhere.

---

And as you can see as well, I update my memory once and it'll stay this way. So it should work for you as well! Like I said, maybe you try to store something that shouldn't be stored.

Comment: i'm only trying to store an object ID as a string, which i can do in other object's memory, so I should be able to store it, but every time i do it instantly reverts to undefined, even when i have absolutely no code running

Comment: I like the idea of a settings module. But why store it in memory at all? Just access the settings directly.